# updating Windows 7 without activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, windows-activation

I wonder either it is really impossible to **update** Windows (**Win 7** in my case) **without having activated** it (i.e. with no product key available) or if the activation is just recommended for doing this kind of maintenance automatically.

Specifically, is there any way to know which updates I need, download and install them **manually** every time I decide to check them and deal with the updating process?

I also tried to check for updates manually by using *windows update mini tool* but every time I start the procedure I got the error message telling me that Windows is not activated:

[image: screen]

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this?  You can create your own .wim file from an updated installation if your attempting to update before you activate.

Comment: Never tried it but this windows update mini tool may allow you to get windows updates, use version 27-01...https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3E95/kvd9WCbUq

Comment: More about this tool...http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/

Comment: @Moab : it didn't work (see additional section in my question), thank you in any case.

Comment: I did this many times using WSUS Offline. That was, of course, right after installing it.

Comment: @DanielB do you mean that Windows lets _Windows Update Mini Tool_ install updates only if I run it immediately after having installed the Operative System (i.e. before the notification telling me that Win is not activated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use windows update when windows is not activated, but the exception is the grace period of a month.

Before you get the nag: You must activate windows, windows will be fully functional. Once you get the message, things like windows update will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, is there any way to know which updates I need

Yep.  Windows will tell you when you purchase a license or provide it with a product key.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, it asks specifically how to do it when it is not activated.

Comment: And "activate it" is a perfectly good answer. The OP is very careful to say "without *having activated it*" rather than, for example, "without activating it", and even added emphasis to make sure this was clear.